# Ffmpeg recording with gdigrab will drop frame

Tags: ffmpeg, recording

I write a code to use gdigrab to capture screen and use dshow to capture audio.

But no matter how I set the frame rate to gdigrab, the acquisition frame rate is 10 frames.

I thought maybe my computer equipments influenced the acquisition frame rate.

Here are the information of computer equipments:

windows 7

1.CPU :Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU  E8400 @ 3.00GHz 3.00GHz

2.RAM :4.00GB (3.48GB available)

3.Screen resolution ：1680*1050

4.adapter information ：Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family

5.Screen refresh frequency ：60HZ

I don't know which is the culprits.Is there any way to detect the highest acquisition frame rate by writing a code.

I really appreciate your help!